# математико-механический или механико-математический факультет

Tags: грамотная-речь

Мне сказали, что правильно говорить математико-механический факультет, но почему не объяснили. Есть ли разница?

Comment: Мне кажется что в разных вузах используются разные названия. В некоторых "математико-механический", в других "механико-математический".

Answer (score 2):

В принципе разницы между *механико-математический* и *математико-механический* почти нет. Первый вариант означает, что на факультете изучают механику и математику, второй - что математику и механику. В принципе в некоторых текстах может быть оговорено различие (так, например, у шахматистов полуоткрытые и полузакрытые дебюты - это не одно и тоже), но как правило разница лишь в порядке слов.

Что касается как правильно в конкретном вузе, то не зная самого учебного заведения, ответить на ваш вопрос невозможно. Правильно так, как написано в документации.

Answer (score 0):

Принципиальной разницы нет, но в русском языке на первое место обычно ставят более важное понятие. Значит,в СПбГУ большее значение имела математика, поэтому матмех,в Москве(МГУ) - механика, поэтому мехмат,

"По воспоминаниям профессора Н. А. Слёзкина, механики играли на факультете более значительную роль, чем математики, и это определило название факультета".
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE-